# What are the common router default DHCP IP address ranges?

Tags: router, dhcp, factory-defaults, default-settings

I'm trying to find out what the default DHCP ranges are for common routers.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 7):

They will only be within

```
http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918

     10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
     172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
     192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
```

And that's not just the defaults, that's all you can set them to too. Those are the 3 private IP ranges. As specified by RFC 1918

Now, as far as what is common. That could change in future. But from what i've seen, the 192.168/16 range is most common.

Second to that is the  10/8 range.  I've seen that too, as you have. It's not uncommon

And I've never seen a router set to use anything on 172.16/12  but they could.

Comment: If you want to find out a router's IP you wouldn't guess it, you'd plug it in and if on NT(e.g. Win XP), you'd run the ipconfig command. No device is ever .0 or .255(though maybe things can be amended to allow it but it'd be very abnormal).  A Router/Gateway would commonly be .1 by default. So any DHCP range would not go from .0 to .255  but from say .1 to .254

Comment: err, that'snot all you can set it to. If you had a 'real' IP range, you could set to your IP range. Of course, this is very very unlikely because of the lack of 'real' IP addresses.

And all the wireless routers I've had were 192.168.1/24. They were low end ones for home use, unlikely to have more than a few devices, so a /24 was adequate.

Comment: @Rich Homolka  ok , they're all real IPs though. The distinction is public and private.

Comment: defaults are in the private ip range, and those private ip ranges I mentioned are all the private IPs. And if using NAT then you're using one public IP and more than one private IP. But I suppose, if NAT is off, then no private IPs, and one or more devices get public IPs.. it may be possible to set them statically in the router for the router's IP and for DHCP. And it's up to the ISP if they give you / you can use more than one (public) IP and if so then what range. It'd be a subset of the IP block/range that the ISP owns.

Answer (score 6):

The vast majority are set to 192.168.1/24.  Additionally, some also default to 192.168.0/24 and then there are a very small number that default to 10.1.1/24 or 10.0.0/24.

(The final octet of the gateway IP {the router's IP address} is almost always .1, although I've seen a few that were defaulted to .254 over the years.)

Comment: Oh, usually the last octet is .100 with 50 or 100 clients (so the range ends at .149 or .199, although some will fudge it up to .150 or .200 respectively and still call it 50 or 100 clients when it's really 51 or 101).

Comment: Is there a specific problem you are trying to resolve?

Comment: linksys is usually 192.168.1.x

Answer (score 3):

Here is a list which I compiled for http://localrouter.net

Mostly culled from http://www.techspot.com/guides/287-default-router-ip-addresses/

```
    var commonDefaults = {  // used by...
        "cellspot.router":  "T-Mobile (ASUS)",
        "10.0.0.1":         "Cisco, D-Link, Sitecom, SMC",
        "10.0.0.2":         "Belkin, Billion, Cisco, D-Link, Siemens, Zoom, Zyxel",
        "10.0.0.138":       "2Wire, Huawei, NetComm, Siemens, SpeedTouch, Zoom, Zyxel",
        "10.0.1.1":         "Apple", // no HTTP
        "10.0.10.1":        "SMC",
        "10.1.1.1":         "Belkin, D-Link",
        "10.10.1.1":        "Asus",
        "10.90.90.90":      "D-Link",
        "172.16.0.1":       "",
        "172.16.1.1":       "",
        "192.168.0.1":      "2Wire, Actiontec, D-Link, Eminent, Huawei, LevelOne, Linksys, Netgear, Planet, Senao, Siemens, Sitecom, SMC, Tenda, Thomson, TP-Link, Trendnet, ZTE, Zyxel",
        "192.168.0.3":      "Sonicwall",
        "192.168.0.10":     "D-Link",
        "192.168.0.30":     "Cisco, D-Link, Trendnet",
        "192.168.0.50":     "Cisco, D-Link",
        "192.168.0.100":    "Trendnet",
        "192.168.0.101":    "D-Link",
        "192.168.0.277":    "Netgear",
        "192.168.0.254":    "TP-Link",
        "192.168.1.1":      "2Wire, 3Com, Actiontec, Airlink, Asus, Aztech, Belkin, Buffalo, Dell, Cisco, D-Link, Eminent, Huawei, Linksys, NetComm, Planet, Repotec, Siemens, SMC, Tenda, TP-Link, Trendnet, USR, Zoom, ZTE, Zyxel, Motorola, Planet, Repotec",
        "192.168.1.10":     "Linksys",
        "192.168.1.99":     "Linksys",
        "192.168.1.100":    "Trendnet",
        "192.169.1.200":    "Hawking",
        "192.168.1.210":    "Linksys",
        "192.168.1.254":    "2Wire, Asus, Aztech, Billion, D-Link, Gigabyte, Hawking, Linksys, Motorola, MSI, Netopia, Planet, Siemens, Sitecom, SpeedTouch, Thomson, Trendnet, Zoom, Zyxel",
        "192.168.2.1":      "Actiontec, Airlink, Airlive, Airties, Asus, Aztech, Belkin, Edimax, Linksys, Microsoft, Siemens, SMC, Trendnet, USR, Zoom, ZTE, Zyxel",
        "192.168.2.254":    "ZTE",
        "192.168.3.1":      "Amped, Huawei",
        "192.168.4.1":      "Zoom, Zyxel",
        "192.168.8.1":      "Eminent, Huawei",
        "192.168.10.1":     "3Com, Motorola, Repotec, Trendnet, Zoom, Zyxel",
        "192.168.10.10":    "Trendnet",
        "192.168.10.50":    "NetComm",
        "192.168.10.100":   "Trendnet",
        "192.168.11.1":     "Buffalo",
        "192.168.15.1":     "D-Link: Linksys: Motorola: Sweex",
        "192.168.16.1":     "Linksys: Repotec",
        "192.168.20.1":     "Motorola: NetComm",
        "192.168.29.1":     "Asus",
        "192.168.30.1":     "Motorola",
        "192.168.50.1":     "Sweex",
        "192.168.55.1":     "Sweex",
        "192.168.62.1":     "Motorola",
        "192.168.100.1":    "Motorola, Huawei, Thomson",
        "192.168.100.100":  "ZTE",
        "192.168.102.1":    "Motorola",
        "192.168.123.254":  "LevelOne, Repotec, Sitecom, USR",
        "192.168.168.168":  "Sonicwall",
        "192.168.223.100":  "Trendnet",
        "192.168.251.1":    "Sweex",
        "192.168.254.254":  "Actiontec, Aztech, D-Link, Siemens, Zyxel"
    };
```